# Partial unique index in postgres in relation to other rows

Tags: postgresql, indexing, unique

I'm aware of partial unique indexes in PostgreSQL in general but I have a need to put in a constraint that doesn't fit into the partial index realm I think. Or maybe there is a way to somehow express it.

Minimal example

```
CREATE TABLE table (user INT, type INT, flag BOOL, text VARCHAR (50));
```

The requirements are:

1. A `user` can have multiple rows of the same `type` but only if `flag` is false.
2. If a `user` has a row with a particular `type` and a `flag` set to true, then there can be no other row for that `user` and `type`.

So if for example the table has the following rows:

```
| user | type | flag  | text |
| 1    | 1    | false | foo  |
| 1    | 1    | false | bar  |
```

then we cannot insert (1, 1, true, 'whatever')

---

Also if the table has:

```
| user | type | flag | text |
| 1    | 1    | true | foo  |
```

Than we cannot insert (1, 1, false, 'bar') nor (1, 1, true, 'baz')

---

Is there a way to express a constraint like that in PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 5):

You need a combination of a [partial unique index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) and an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE). Unfortunately, there is no operator family which can be used for a boolean column in an exclusion constraint, so an integer column may be used instead. The [btree_gist extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) is necessary to emulate gist index for integer columns.

```
create extension if not exists btree_gist;
```

The table definition (identifiers modified a bit):

```
drop table if exists my_table;
create table my_table (
    user_id integer,
    type_id integer, 
    flag integer check (flag in (0, 1)),
    text varchar (50),
    exclude using gist (user_id with =, type_id with =, flag with <>)
);

create unique index on my_table (user_id, type_id) where flag = 1;
```

Exemplary insertions:

```
insert into my_table
values
(1, 1, 0, 'foo'),
(1, 1, 0, 'bar'),
(2, 2, 1, 'foo');

INSERT 0 3

insert into my_table
values
(1, 1, 1, 'whatever');

ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "my_table_user_id_type_id_flag_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, type_id, flag)=(1, 1, 1) conflicts with existing key (user_id, type_id, flag)=(1, 1, 0).

insert into my_table
values
(2, 2, 0, 'whatever');

ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "my_table_user_id_type_id_flag_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, type_id, flag)=(2, 2, 0) conflicts with existing key (user_id, type_id, flag)=(2, 2, 1).

insert into my_table
values
(2, 2, 1, 'whatever');

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_user_id_type_id_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, type_id)=(2, 2) already exists.
```